# Lavaplayer зависает, когда нужно воспроизвести музыку

Tags: java, бот, maven, discord-jda

Пишу музыкального бота для discord. Столкнулся с проблемой, что ни один код не воспроизводит музыку, даже полностью скопированный из руководства, у автора которого стоят аналогичные версии, и при этом код выполняет свою функцию. Дальнейшее изучение проблемы привело к тому, что программа зависает на строчке:

```
player.startTrack(track, false);
```

Зависание так же происходит, если заменить строку выше на:

```
player.playTrack(track);
```

Так же при использовании /play пробовал вводить ссылки на разные платформы и треки на них, но ничего не помогает.

На просторах интернета нашел информацию давностью в несколько лет, что некоторые платформы ограничили доступ к загрузке с них для ботов. При этом руководство, код которого я тестировал, было выпущено в феврале этого года. Таким образом, я склоняюсь, что проблема все-таки на моей стороне.